# Error 500 when accessing URL - Centos 6 (selinux disabled) - NGINX - PHP-fpm and GITList

Tags: nginx, centos6, git, php-fpm

Installed Centos 6 (selinux disabled) - NGINX - PHP-fpm and GITList. when I access my URL I get a server error (The website encountered an error while retrieving http://git.sastratechnologies.net/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.)

Here is what I did
1. Installed php (php and php-fpm)
2. Configure php (cgi.fix_pathinfo=0)
3. Configure /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and replaced user and group with nginx
4. Changed nginx default.conf and increased worker process to 4
5. Created a virtual host by mapping an URL. Tested with php.info and found it working
6. Removed php.info.
7. Followed the instructions on github and installed gitlist by cloning, created cache directory, made it writable, changed paths in config.ini
7. Used the nginx virtual host configuration provided in the installation instructions on GitHub(I noticed the listen directive missing. I had to Include the listen directive to listen on git.sastratechnologies.net without it I was being redirected to the other vhost that had bugzilla. Changed the paths appropriately restarted nginx
8. Accessed the URL and I get the server error 500
9. Access log has the entry (122.164.43.240 - - [14/Aug/2013:14:47:13 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-") and Error logs do not have entries

I then went on to install Osticket and used the VHOST configuration provided in the NGINX wiki, I get the same error. Has anyone had a similar experience. Would like to hear from you.

Comment: For whatever its worth. I have been able to get Osticket working. The issue was with the PHP-Fpm port in the Nginx vhost file I had mentioned fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888 so changed it to fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 because in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf had listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by downloading gitlist from gitlist.org rather than cloning it from github.